# Is there a way to open I/O files without access to c:drive?

Tags: c#

I do C# on a school tablet where the c:drive is blocked by the administrator and don't have a flashdrive and I'm not able to open io files

```
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace HandlingExceptions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExceptionTest();
        }
        private static void ExceptionTest()
        {
            StreamReader sr = null;
            try
            {
                sr = File.OpenText(@"c:\data.txt");
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fnfe.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine but if there any ajustments to be made on the line that has `sr = File.OpenText(@"c:\data.txt");`

Comment: "open io files" What do you mean here? Opening a file is surely an **Input/Output**-operation. So when you can´t open a file because of missing permissions, you can´t open the file.

Comment: Sounds like something you need to speak to your administrator about

Comment: Have you tried a different path inside the C drive? It just may be that the root of the C drive is protected by the administrator but you would be able to write the file if it's located in a sub-directory or even in your execution path.

Comment: How about taking a file from the my documents folder `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, "data.txt")`

Comment: "The code works fine" ??? If it works fine then what is the problem? Do you get an exception - if so what is it?

Answer (score 3):

Your questions indicate you don't know what and why are you doing. The best thing you have to do is visiting your teacher or classmate and ask him, what this code does.

You are trying to open the file and read it. So, one problem is fact that given file probably does not even exists. You can't read non-existing file.

Second problem are permissions - on sane system (and even on Windows), users cannot (should not!) be able to write to "system" directories, users should have their own space for files (documents, etc). You have that space too - as you were able to save this source code, you should be able to open/save whatever else.

So, ideally, try to change that path to either your home directory or in current directory.

Path of your home directory can be found by `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%");`. When you want to use current directory, you just use file name without any path like `File.OpenText("data.txt");` - this will (when using Visual Studio with default settings) open `data.txt` file in folder where program executable is created.